# Can I use t-test to test for a observation within a sample to see if it's an outlier

Tags: time-series, t-test, outliers

I have a basic question, I am tracking loan defaults month on month and I want to see if due to a fall in the interest rates if my defaults have fallen in August. I was thinking of taking the average of default rates until July from the start of the year and comparing the August value with the mean value of defaults and running a t-test on both these value to see if the new value is significantly different mean for the year so far.

Is this a correct way to analyze this problem or I am thinking incorrectly?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable approach for what you want to find out. I would say though that outlier is potentially a misleading term to use. The term implies observations that are extreme and unexpected, but what you really just want to know is whether there's a change. Now, if loan defaults were the same every month of the year, but they dropped dramatically in August then that could be considered an outlier in the general trend (i.e. that nothing changes), but this isn't necessarily what you're interested in.

Comment: This is a time series and comes with all the troubles in time series. If there is a general trend of falling values from january to august, than this test will become positive, even if there is nothing special about august. Maybe there is a general trend, that each year's August has special loan defaults because some people make more money in August independent of the interest rates?  t-Tests are made for independent observations and these are probably not independent observations. If you use the t-test anyways, you should at least investigate and discuss these problems.

Comment: as @Bernhard already outlined you have to take care about time series effects. In your case there is surely seasonality. Unemployment in Central and Northern Europe is higher in winter than in summer. Therefore presumably also the default rate for credits is higher.  long-time economic cycles give you a "kind of seasonality over the years". I propose you make a Unit root test between July and August in order to test whether the structure of the time series changes significantly between July and August. An ADF-Test, KPSS-Test or Philipp-Perron test might perform better than a simple t-test.

Comment: @Ferdi Mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

This is a time series and comes with all the troubles in time series. If there is a general trend of falling values from january to august, than this test will become positive, even if there is nothing special about august. Maybe there is a general trend, that each year's August has special loan defaults because some people make more money in August independent of the interest rates? t-Tests are made for independent observations and these are probably not independent observations. If you use the t-test anyways, you should at least investigate and discuss these problems. – Bernhard

as @Bernhard already outlined you have to take care about time series effects. In your case there is surely seasonality. Unemployment in Central and Northern Europe is higher in winter than in summer. Therefore presumably also the default rate for credits is higher. long-time economic cycles give you a "kind of seasonality over the years". I propose you make a Unit root test between July and August in order to test whether the structure of the time series changes significantly between July and August. An ADF-Test, KPSS-Test or Philipp-Perron test might perform better than a simple t-test. – Ferdi

As this is a time-series problem, you should treat it as such. You could simply use control charts (from quality control methods) [here some relevant posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=control-chart+time+series+answers%3A1).  Or you could treat it as a question about [detecting change points in a time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=change-point+time+series+answers%3A1+score%3A3).